# Netezza SQL Join dataset A to dataset B but pull fields from B when b_date > a_date

Tags: sql, left-join, netezza

I have 2 datasets from 2 different sources but many of the members are the same in both datasets.  My select statement is :

```
Select a.member_id, a.start_date, a.customer_id, a.region_id, b.b_start_date, b.customer_id, b.region_id
from dataset1 a
left join dataset2 b
on a.member_id=b.member_id
```

I want to somehow pick up all recs in A and recs in B where a.member_id = b.member_id but bring in the fields `from A when a.start_date = b.b_start_date or a.start_date >  b.b_start_date` and bring in the fields `from B when b.b_start_date > a.start_date`.

Here's a pretty small example:

Dataset A:

| member_id | start_date | customer_id | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1/30/2021 | 123 | 555 |
| 2222 | 1/30/2021 | 222 | 555 |
| 3333 | 1/1/2021 | 345 | 678 |

Dataset B:

| member_id | b_start_date | customer_id | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1/1/2022 | 567 | 444 |
| 2222 | 1/30/2021 | 222 | 555 |

Result:

| member_id | customer_id | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 567 | 444 |
| 2222 | 222 | 555 |
| 3333 | 345 | 678 |

Answer (score 1):

```
/* try this */

select a.* from a inner join b using (member_id) where a.start_date >= b.b_start_date
union all
select b.* from a inner join b using (member_id) where b.b_start_date > a.start_date;
```

Comment: I didn't give a good example.  The A dataset has a lot of fields that are not in the B dataset and can have more members than B dataset.  Some of the members are the same in both datasets. The B dataset has fields that are not in the A dataset. If the B start date > the A start date pull all fields from both datasets. If the members are the same in both A and B and b.start_date > a.start_date, and the fieldnames are common in the two datasets, overwrite the values in A with the values from B.  I can only join on member id so that makes it challenging also

Comment: I would like to attach a document with a better example but can't find where to do the attachment